# Weird datastore error in Go, "The kind is the empty string"

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am recently getting an error that I have never seen before when making a simple datastore.GetAll() request.  I can't figure out what it means and I can't find any documentation with the error message or any help from Googleing the error message.

Here's my code:

```
type MyUnderlyingStruct struct {
    ApplyTo             *datastore.Key
    ApplyFrom           *datastore.Key
    Amount              float64
    LocationKey         *datastore.Key
    DepartmentKey       *datastore.Key
    SubjectAreaKey      *datastore.Key
}

type MyStruct []MyUnderlyingStruct 

//In the case where I get the error someKey is a valid, complete Key value
//  of a different kind that what we are querying for and there is actually
//  an entity in my datastore that matches this query
func (x *MyStruct) Load(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, someKey *datastore.Key) (error) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    q := datastore.NewQuery("MyUnderlyingStruct_KindName").Order("-Amount")
    if someKey != nil { q = q.Filter("ApplyTo=", someKey) }

    keys, err := q.GetAll(c,x)
    if _, ok := err.(*datastore.ErrFieldMismatch); ok { err = nil }
    if err != nil && err != datastore.Done {return err}
    return nil
}
```

Which returns this error:

```
API error 1 (datastore_v3: BAD_REQUEST): The kind is the empty string.
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error, or what it is trying to tell me?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you reverse the order of the `Order()` and `Filter()`?  (It shouldn't, but I'm curious!).

Comment: You sure it's not zeroed-memory initialization from `new` keyword you use to create MyStruct instance? 0 maps to "" for any string field in a struct.

Comment: Definitely makes no difference if I switch Order() and Filter().  I'm looking into the zeroed-memory init theory now...

Comment: @pie-o-pah MyStruct is really a slice, which I init with `mySlice := new(MyStruct, 0)`, which I do plenty of time in other code.  I don't think that is the issue, unless it is with the underlying struct which consists of five *datastore.Key properties, and one float64 property, nothing fancy, and all of those properties should zero out without any problems I would think.

Comment: @pie-o-pah, see my edits to the original post for the declarations of all of the different types.

Comment: @pie-o-pah, I figured it out thanks to your help!  It was related to the way that I was initializing something, but I was looking at all the wrong somethings.  The function in my code actually takes a few more parameters (all keys that will create other `.Filters()` if not nil).  They all should have been nil as I am not actually using them yet, and I assumed that they were.  I was initializing one of them using `myKey := new(datastore.Key)`, which I never do; the others using `var myKey2 *datastore.Key`, which I always use. The former creates an incomplete key, the latter creates a nil key.

Comment: @pie-o-pah, if you create an answer to this question based on your comment, I will select it as the official answer so that you can get the rep points

Comment: Wow, okay glad I can help. Thanks for the generosity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your issue on the first glance (because I am not familiar with Google's datastore API), it seems to me the problem is a result of zeroed-memory initialization using `new` keyword.

When a struct is created with the keyword without assigning starting values for the fields, 0's are given as default. When mapped to string, it's "" (empty). Go actually threw a very helpful error for you.

As you have pointed out, you have used `Mykey := new(datastore.Key)`. Thanks for your generosity and this can serve as answer for future users.